microtype messing with a table
I'm using longtable to typeset a glossary.
When microtype is enabled, it starts looking wrong as the first line of wrapped text in a cell gets shifted to the right.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}
    @{}}
    MWE: & \emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Results in this:

If I comment out \usepackage{microtype} above, it looks good:

it also happens without the \emph, I've just been testing various texts and this example makes the issue particularly noticeable.
This is pdflatex from texlive 2024.2
Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
Edit: I'm now working around this by disabling microtype for the table as per this Answer

Interesting.  This is unrelated to longtable: the issue occurs also with a simple tabular. It's an interaction between array and microtype.

Thanks for finding out, I updated the MWE and removed the longtable tag.

microtype can not apply the left protrusion in the first line. But you could add it manually:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{3cm}
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6cm}
    @{}}
    MWE: & \leftprotrusion\emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \emph{Why} does microtype break this table? \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}



Do you know some more details on why it cannot do this automatically? Is there a way to fix it without add \leftprotrusion to every cell?

@Gamification The problem is that in tables, tex expands macros at the beginning of cells, so microtype doesn't recognise the original \emph. I'll see what can be done. (For now, {\em Why} would also work, with less keystrokes.)
